# Lost all virtual host setting after tomcat7 restart

Tags: tomcat7, virtualhost, virtual-hosts

I have a problem with setting a new hosts in Tomcat7 host-manager application. Host-manager application works very well. Everything works. But when restart the server, all settings are lost. I have to everything set up again.

1.I start Tomcat7 host-manager

http://localhost:8080/host-manager/html
2.Set up Hosts

3.Everything works

4.Restart server

/etc/init.d/tomcat7 restart
6.The settings are lost. There are not Hosts. I have to all set up again.
goto 1

note:
I use Ubuntu 14.04 and tomcat7